# выделить другим цветом ссылку, которая перевела на определенную часть страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница, навигация по ней работает по ссылкам, каждая ссылка ведет на определенную часть страницы.

Как сделать так, что бы ссылка меняла свой цвет (если она активная на данный момент)?

Comment: Дабы лучше понять, что Вы имеете в виду, приложите код.

Comment: вот тут пример, http://jsbin.com/ezohic/1/edit?html,css,js,output, как сделать так что бы ссылка на которую мы кликнули на пример Malone выделилась красным?

Comment: вот еще пример, если выбрали five то эта же ссылка подсветится https://www.howtomake.com.ua/demo/how-to-make-plavnaya-navigaciya-na-stranice

Comment: у меня ссылки имеют вид <a href="#link">link</a> и ведет она на часть страницы к элементу с id="link"

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, возможно он решит вашу задачу

Comment: спасибо, как сделать так, когда колесом мышки прокручиваешь фрагменты страницы, соответствующий якорь подсветился, вот прокрутили в sec3 подсветилась ссылка sec3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Немного мимо кассы, но с jQuery как-то так можно это сделать (вдруг кому-то пригодится)

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  let navEl = $(this);
  let scrollElement = $(this).attr("href");
  let scrollOffset = $(scrollElement).offset().top;
  if (!navEl.hasClass("active")) {
    $(".link").removeClass("active");
    navEl.addClass("active");
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: scrollOffset
    }, 1100);
  }
});
```

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

.link {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: grey;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.body div {
  height: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#sec1" class="link active">sec1</a>
  <a href="#sec2" class="link">sec2</a>
  <a href="#sec3" class="link">sec3</a>
  <a href="#sec4" class="link">sec4</a>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div id="sec1">sec1</div>
  <div id="sec2">sec2</div>
  <div id="sec3">sec3</div>
  <div id="sec4">sec4</div>
</div>
```